# What is the shortcut key to go backwards and forwards through tabs in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

If you have several firefox tabs open, what do you press to go back and forth between them? I.e. scroll left and right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use Ctrl + Tab to go forward and Ctrl + Shift + Tab to go back.

Answer (score 11):

Or if you want to go to a specific tab you can hit **ctrl + [Number]**

Comment: What do you do if you go more than 10 tabs?

Comment: I think you can only go 0 - 9 with that method.  If you have more than 9 you'll have to use one of the other methods mentioned

Answer (score 7):

I've been using Ctrl + PgUp for the previous tab and Ctrl + PgDn for the next tab.  I like this shortcut, because I can also use it on Excel spreadsheets.

Comment: Have you changed the default keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: No, it's a default shortcut, I always used this as well. Now Vimperator has it on gt and gT, so I use them.

Comment: This keyboard shortcut can be used too in Eclipse, for moving between editors.

Answer (score 2):

Control-Tab will cycle forward through tabs.  I don't know if it's possible to cycle backward, haven't been worried enough to try.

Comment: Just use shift. This is consistent with almost every place where you can use Tab; Tab goes forward, Shift+Tab goes back.

Answer (score 1):

Related to the question, you could use [Tab Wheel Scroll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6501) to switch tabs using the mouse scroll wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I use [All-in-One Gestures](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12). Left for previous and right for next tab. That is default for history back and forward, but Left Click + Right Click (for forward) and Right Click + Left Click (for back) is quite useful for history, so I remaped left and right gesture.